# Swift 2: "Bool' is not convertible to 'BooleanLiteralConvertible'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller, swift2

I created an app in `XCode 6`. Today I downloaded `XCode 7` and it had updated my app to `Swift 2`. There were a lot of errors, but now there is only one that I can't solve.
I don't know why, but `Xcode` doesn't like any `Bool` option for `animated` and show this error -

> 'Bool' is not convertible to 'BooleanLiteralConvertible'

(if you look at the function itself, you will see, that it takes exactly the `Bool` for `animated`)

```
var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(indexImage) as ContentViewController
var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

self.pageViewContorller.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    'Bool' is not convertible to 'BooleanLiteralConvertible'
```

Does anybody know, how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a typo "pageViewContorller"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swift is confused and giving you an incorrect error message.  The problem is that the first parameter is of type `[UIViewController]?`, so the following should work:

```
self.pageViewContorller.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or even better, declare `viewControllers` to be of type `[UIViewController]` then no casting is needed in the call:

```
let viewControllers:[UIViewController] = [startVC]
self.pageViewContorller.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid casting if possible. The Swift 1 [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPageViewController/setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:) for `- setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` has changed from:

```
func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [AnyObject]!,
          direction direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection,
           animated animated: Bool,
         completion completion: ((Bool) -> Void)!)
```

to

```
func setViewControllers(viewControllers: [UIViewController]?,
          direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection,
           animated: Bool,
         completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

so your cast confuses Swift 2 because the type `[AnyObject]` of `viewControllers` doesn't match `[UIViewController]?`. Expect more Objective-C APIs to be audited in the future.

First fix `viewControllerAtIndex` to return a `UIViewController`:

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController {
    ...
}
```

then just let Swift infer the correct types:

```
let startVC = viewControllerAtIndex(indexImage)

let viewControllers = [startVC]

pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers,
    direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

which is the readable version of:

```
let startVC: UIViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(indexImage)

let viewControllers: [UIViewController] =
    Array<UIViewController>(arrayLiteral: startVC)

pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers,
    direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward,
    animated: true, completion: nil)
```